# Error in the getJSON() call of the new Google Time Zone API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the new 
[Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

I use it to know the exact time in a lat/long point of the map.

First of all, I read that Google launched this api for 6 days ago (10 oct 2012), so I have found no documentation about this API calls.

I have the following problem:

Google forces you to use https, and I get the cross domain error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=35.209722,-118.300781&timestamp=1350372338&sensor=false Origin http://my_web is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

This is my code to obtain the JSON:

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=35.209722,-118.300781&timestamp=1350372338&sensor=false";  
$.ajax({  
                 url: url,  
                 //data: {},  
                 type: "GET",  
                 crossDomain: true,  
                 dataType: 'json',  
                 //processData: false,  

                 success: function (data) {  
                     console.log('Succes!! Read some data...');  
                 },  
                 error: function (xhr, err) {  
                     console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);  
                     console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);  
                 }  
             });
```

In many posts recommend using JSONP instead of JSON, but the problem is that Google only provides the response in JSON and XML.

Does anyone know how I can make a GET request for https without the problem of cross domain?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how I can make a GET request for https without the problem of cross domain?

This is a web service, retrieve it from your server (or use a proxy on your server).

Comment: So I will not be able to query from Javascript? 
With Geonames service I have no problems because it is http, not https.
So it seems that the problem is that the URL is https type? Because with http URLs if that works. Thanks!

Comment: Finally I make the call from a php. From Javascript is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get that working using [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) You can use it with a json call to retreive json data.

Inside the console you need to put something like

```
select * from html where url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=35.209722,-118.300781&timestamp=1350372338&sensor=false"
```

and you can see the result. Below some sample pseudo code. You need to find out yourself what you can use for xpath (if needed)

```
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=35.209722,-118.300781&timestamp=1350372338&sensor=false';
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '" AND xpath="....."') + '&format=json&callback=?';  
$.getJSON(yql,function(data){  
    if(data.results){
     ... do your thing here with the data
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that this is a way to transform the response in JSONP? Thanks!

Comment: yep, and a way to overcome the `same origin policy` that causes your error message